# What bag do you use for your field recorder?

Tags: field-recording, bag

When I bought my Sound Devices 722 I also bought a purpose built Camrade bag for it:
http://www.camrade.com/products-page/audio/other/ab-sd-01
which seems good in terms of being waterproof, but I'm planning my Samoa record trip & am wondering if there is a better option as I'll be travelling with more gear than usual... 
So what bag do you use for your field recorder?
Please include a link to the model and/or a photo

Answer (score 1):

Currently using an old Russian gas mask bag:

[image]

It works for now, as my field recording rig only consists of an H4n and a Röde NTG-2.
That wonderful day I can afford a Sound Device I'll have to upgrade :)

Answer (score 0):

We've used the old standard PortaBrace at work for a long time, but we're switching over to petrol bags. We have [this one](http://www.petrolbags.com/Sound-Bags?q=node/103) (Eargonizer - Large) for use with our Deva 5.8, and we're looking into the new [Deca Eargonizer - Small](http://www.petrolbags.com/Sound-Bags?q=node/1180) for our 744t/302 combo. The bags are extremely customizable, and I've been very impressed with the one we currently have (we've also got the full harness for that one, which is awesome). They might be worth looking into for your trip.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [large Petrol Deca Eargonizer](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/686614-REG/Petrol_PS602_PS602_Deca_Eargonizer_Bag.html).  Great bag. Like it more than the Porta Brace stuff we have. It's quieter, softer, and nicer all around.  Use it with a 744T and a Deva Fusion 10.

For the harness, I use a [Versa-Flex](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/439284-REG/Versa_Flex_HS1N.html).  Most comfortable one out there.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Tim,

I'm a big fan of the portabrace stuff.  I use this bag:

http://www.portabrace.com/productA-AR-7

I like it for a few reasons:

1. the inputs and outputs are easily reached and you can use the velcro to keep the bag fixed open or fixed closed depending on your needs.
2. Access to the battery pack . . .  the bottom has a velcro opening which means you never have to take the recorder out of the bag to change batteries.  This is a huge time saver.  I'm so thankful for that bottom flap.
   http://www.portabrace.com/assets/images/ar-7d.jpg
3. The portabrace series is also very modular, which means you can strap on different front pouches based on your needs.  You can even attach another recorder on the front of the bag.

The main drawback of this series of bag is all of the velcro . . .   I know I just told you that I love it so much, but when you occasionally forget to fix your panels open and you are recording it can suck to get the bag open quietly.  I can't tell you how many times I've had to use my pinkie to adjust the volume of my headphones because the side panel of my bag is closed and I'm in record.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Petrol Deca PS607: http://www.petrolbags.com/PS607 and am very happy with it for toting my 702T.  I definitely prefer it to the Portabraces due to the reduced use of velcro (quieter, no grinding one's fingers up when reaching for side knobs/connections) and it seems quite durable.

I also took a page out of Chuck's book and recently grabbed a Timbuk2 messenger bag for carrying recorder + up to *two* mics in zeppelins + headphones + matrix amp + miscellaneous.  I'm traveling soon as well and plan to use this bag as my carry-on so as not to let the airlines/TSA potentially maim my stuff.  I think it's this one: http://www.rei.com/product/789263 (you can get it way cheaper than this at non-REI stores -- mine was on clearance at Sport Chalet for $59).

Answer (score 0):

What bag I use depends on what I'm doing, and how.

I have yet to make the jump to Petrol, which many recordists prefer, so I'm still rockin' the [Portabrace AR-7](http://www.portabrace.com/productA-AR-7) like @sepulchra. I like having the wireless pouch mounted on it for the bits and bobs needed in the field, even if there's no wireless involved. The velcro is definitely not stealthy. I sometimes carry it on my chest using a [LowePro-brand chest harness](http://products.lowepro.com/product/Topload-Zoom-Chest-Harness,2054.htm) for the TopLoader series...unlike production audio harnesses like the Versa-Flexes, there is no padding on that harness, allowing it to be worn under any backpack.

As per @Ryan's comment/plug, I do use Maxpedition brand bags for more stealthy carry in urban areas, specifially the [Lunada](http://www.maxpedition.com/store/pc/Lunada-Gearslinger-2p484.htm) and the [Sitka](http://www.maxpedition.com/store/pc/Sitka-Gearslinger-2p926.htm). I've come to like the Sitka better, because it's designed to swing around the body and be opened while horizontal, and it's a better size for carrying more of a day's worth of clothing, food, and so forth. I also use my old, beat-up [Chrome messenger bag](http://www.chromebagsstore.com/bags/messenger-bags/metropolis-buckle-bag---large.html) sometimes when I need to carry mics, a windscreen, and the recorder in the same bag while keeping a low profile. The problem with messenger bags is that the flap opens towards your body, which makes keeping it open while recording a wee bit more fiddly than I usually like, but it works when the context is right.

All other times I keep all my gear in two 6'-long Pelican cases that my intern carries around on his back. Because that's heavy, I've strapped an espresso machine to his chest to balance his load, and to make those long days of field recording so much nicer for me. :-p

*[J/K]*

Comment: You know I've got your back!

Comment: @noisejockey I too am a chrome devotee.  I have an earlier version of this bag http://www.chromebagsstore.com/bags/packs/ranchero-messenger-pack---medium.html I can often fit the 744 in protabrace bag, my zeppelin, DPA 4060s and laptop.  I often cruise around NYC on my bike with all of that crap.

Comment: Hah, totally - I have a Metrop and one of their gargantuan backpacks, both pretty oldschool. After the founders sold the company, though, some of them have a new joint - check 'em out, they're 2 blocks from my office: http://www.missionworkshop.com/ I've seen the bags in person and the backpacks are brilliantly designed. 

Comment: Yeah, i have a bag that was still made by the original peeps and I've seen those mission bags, but I'm not on the market for another "hipster-spec" bag at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I've just bought a [Timbuk2](http://www.timbuk2.com/) messenger bag that is really useful to hold a lot of gear and keep it waterproof. I prefer to use a [Petrol Pegz-1F](http://www.petrolbags.com/PEGZ-1F) for my recorder, but the messenger bag is great for all my other kit. Mr Noise Jockey has also written a very useful post on the subject of [carrying your gear in the field](http://www.sonic-terrain.com/2010/09/portage-i-the-mil-spec-way/) over at Sonic Terrain...

Comment: oops, just realised Ryan already put a link for Nathan's Sonic Terrain post! 

Answer (score 0):

I use the Petrol Ergonizer series with the back webbing add-on.  It leaves your hands free and is more comfortable (in my opinion) than the Portabrace bags.  For SFX recording, I'll sometimes take a laptop case - it's got enough compartment to store mics and is a less conspicuous in urban environments than an audio bag.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone experimented with police tactical bags?

http://www.mycopshop.com/category.cfm/policesupplies/cases

This  place is  down the road from my parents and tomorrow I am going to bring my 416/with zepplin and recorder out there and see if I can find something that it will all fit into safely for low profile city adventures of the unexpected recording, while maintaining ease of access.

I have an fr2 LE atm but I want to make sure it can/will be able to fit a 7 series or nomad.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little company in Berlin which produces customizable bags for anything You can think of.
The company´s owner knows what we recordists need because he´s also a tonmeister.
Go check the site, which is in german, but You get the point...
the link directly brings You to the list of hardware bags...
so no german needed.

Did I say that I highly recommend these bags???

http://www.filmtontechnik.de/taschenanfertigung.html

If You need to contact them for further questions, don´t hesitate to mail them,
the tailors all speak english !

mail@filmtontechnik.de

p.s.
I don´t work for them, just a convinced customer :-)

Best
L

Answer (score -1):

there is a brand "bebopbag" ; designs and produces custom bags for film and audio equipment. The bags are protective, durable and waterproof. Also the design is cool when compared with other industrial bags. There is a facebook fan page; you can see some of their models.

https://www.facebook.com/bebopdesign?ref=hl