# Which bags you use?

Tags: bag, transport-bag, protection, equipment

Simple, which bags you use for caring your equipment and why?

Answer (score 1):

A number of good discussions on recorder bags can be found by using the site's search feature.  One such good one is here: 
[What bag do you use for your field recorder?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/3946/what-bag-do-you-use-for-your-field-recorder)

Answer (score 1):

I have had my bags all custom made, primarily due to the cost implication of importing the bags vs getting them made.  This has also allowed my to develop some unique designs and systems to make my life easier!  :)